# How to combine java nested list and sum specific variable

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following classes and define below how they are link together:

1. I have a class Order
2. Order contains a list of Items
3. Each item contains a list of taxes

Tax class is defined below

```
public class Tax
   
    private BigDecimal taxRate;


    private BigDecimal taxPayable;

...
```

Basically I need to do the sum of taxPayable for **all** items, any idea how I can achieve this please using the java stream api?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using the Stream Api you will want to use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten a `Stream<Stream<BigDecimal>>` into a `Stream<BigDecimal>` and then use [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to sum the numbers.

Assuming your classes are defined as follows:

```java
class Order {
    public List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    public List<Tax> taxes;
}

class Tax {
    public BigDecimal taxPayable;
    public BigDecimal taxRate;
}
```

Then the following code can be used to find the sum of all the tax payables for all the items in an order:

```java
BigDecimal sum = order.items
    .stream()
    .flatMap(item -> { //Flatten the streams for each of the items into a signle stream
        return taxes.stream().map(tax -> tax.taxPaybale) //Convert an item to a stream of taxPayable
    })
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b)
```

Comment: Thnks a lot for the explanation and works like a charm

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I set up an example to demonstrate.

```
List<Tax> taxList1 = List.of(new Tax(new BigDecimal("10.2")),
        new Tax(new BigDecimal("14.8")));
List<Tax> taxList2 = List.of(new Tax(new BigDecimal("14.2")),
        new Tax(new BigDecimal("22.8")));
List<Tax> taxList3 = List.of(new Tax(new BigDecimal("9.2")),
        new Tax(new BigDecimal("14.2")));
List<Tax> taxList4 = List.of(new Tax(new BigDecimal("18.3")),
        new Tax(new BigDecimal("33.1")));

List<Item> items1 = List.of(new Item(taxList1), new Item(taxList2));
List<Item> items2 = List.of(new Item(taxList3), new Item(taxList4));

List<Order> orders = List.of(new Order(items1), new Order(items2));
```

The streaming process.  Stream the various lists until you get to the tax object.  Then retrieve that using a method reference. Then use a reduction to sum the taxes.

```
        
BigDecimal sum = orders.stream()
        .flatMap(order -> order.getItems().stream())
        .flatMap(item -> item.getTaxes().stream())
        .map(Tax::getTaxPayable)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
136.8
```

The classes

```
class Order {
    List<Item> items;
    
    public Order(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}

class Item {
    List<Tax> taxes;
    
    public Item(List<Tax> taxes) {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }
    
    public List<Tax> getTaxes() {
        return taxes;
    }
}

class Tax {
    
    public Tax(BigDecimal taxPayable) {
        this.taxPayable = taxPayable;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTaxPayable() {
        return taxPayable;
    }
    private BigDecimal taxRate;
    
    private BigDecimal taxPayable;
}
```